# Changing the range of the coordinates on Blender's Viewport

Tags: python, 3d-view, coordinates

I have got Geospatial Data, which has real world coordinates. The minimum and maximums of these coordinates are as follows:

```
         X     Y        Z
min    10000   10000  340
max    30000   30000  1100
```

I wish to fit all the view of Blender, in this range. How would that be possible, either by using the Blender GUI or the Blender Python API.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the scale option.

In the image below the real world block is 480 x 480 km, scale is used to map it onto 16 x 16 blender units. Once that choice is made, divide your coordinates by

```
scene.unit_settings.scale_length
```

when importing, calculated to give you the correct dimensions in the unit of your data.

[image: Options]
[image: SMTP]