# how to create metric map and metric buildings/vehicles/etc in blender?

Tags: customization, units, measurement

I'm going to create a metric map with scale 1000 x 1000 meters then create buildings and roads and vehicles with the same size as real world size. a project for both animation and export to unity 3D. 
1. how can i create a plane with 1000x1000 meters in metric unit in blender?
2. how can i create buildings, vehicles as real size in metrics?
[image]

Comment: As far as I understand, everything you create is entirely relative to everything else within the scene. So if you create a cube and size it down to `0.1`, then create a plane and have it's size values at 100x100, you basically get a `1km`x`1km` plane, relative to the cube. Are you going to export the map to another software or use it in any other way other than within blender?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i want to create animations but maybe i export it to unity for coding.

Comment: yes i want a plane with 1km x 1km, possible to resize in metric units? and where can i resize it?

Comment: I think what you want then is this: [Manual/Interface/Units - BlenderWiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rayek/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Units)

Comment: Also, I suggest you edit your post to clarify what exactly you want and perhaps be more specific. e.g that you specifically want to use metric units

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rayek/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Units

Comment: i saw this link but how can i use this section while creating plane/buildings/vehicles?

Comment: i found the way but new problems are 1. how to use scale value in units section    2. how to change camera and grid size after change to 1km they are so little

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39386/changing-the-range-of-the-coordinates-on-blenders-viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Units are chosen exactly where you are looking at. If you choose metric units and set the scale to 0.001, the unit will be 1mm, and if you set the scale to 1.00, the unit will be 1 meter, that would be appropriate for your purpose.

[image]

You can then use any units in relation to these settings. If you typed 1km into dimension inputs of a plane, it would be scaled to 1000 units(1000 meters):

[image]

Note that you might need to adjust clipping planes of the viewport and your cameras for everything to be displayed correctly as well.

Answer (score 2):

How to scale units from blender to unity?

Go into blender
Scene > unit presets > 
change length to metric
Angles: radians
Unit scale: 1 
[image: enter image viewport here]

Next, in our 3d viewport, the meters at the top left. this only means the grid space now understands metric units and tells us that the grid is measured in meters.

[image]

Not that our cube is now exactly one metric meter 
It is clearly 2 metric meters
[image]

Next 
Select the cube  > open “n” properties tab in the 3d view port > shift + left click drag on top of the x,y,z > set scale from 0.5 to 1

[image]

Next in 
Object > Apply > scale

[image]

Notice scale is now set to ones.

[image]

Next 
Export as either obj or FBX from blender > remember to name your file

[image]

Make sure only selected objects  and mesh is highlighted

[image]

Then hit export
Next 
Open up unity > game object > 3d object > cube

[image]

To preview a Unity cube 
Next 
Import our cube by right-clicking in the empty space inside assets folder

[image]

Import new asset

[image]

Browse for the FBX file we just created

[image]

import

[image]

Left click and drag the model into the scene to compare to the Unity cube

[image]

Comment: I would recommend viewing angles as degrees. (ie choose degrees) The values are saved internally as radians.

Comment: yes, degrees is better for it allows us to see rotation snap in Blender. By using ctrl + mouse drag then left click to confirm new rotation.