# Coordinate XYZ limitation of 10,000 - Workaround questions

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, coordinates

Blender has a limit of 10,000 for the coordinates of the X, Y, Z component of the location’s value of the vertices in edit mode.

[image]

This causes a problem for editing large objects like mountains or large meshes for a game scenery. I understood the Blender’s developers limited the range to 10,000 because there is a precision loss. Seriously, I don’t care that much about the precision for mountains seen in the distance in a game.

I see two workarounds at the moment.

1. Moving the vertices manually.

Although we cannot set the location’s value beyond 10,000 when typing in the location X, Y, Z fields, we can always move the vertices with the vertex arrows in the 3D viewport. However, that is painful. There is not way to be precise.

2. Scaling down the object.

For example, a mountain mesh could be created with 1 / 10 the target size. Then set the scale to 10. The object in the scene appears the same size. When editing the vertices, all the coordinates of the vertices’ location are 1 / 10 of the target values. A value of 2,500 will be equivalent to 25,000.

Does anyone here have other ways to work with this limitation?

Comment: Well, you'll get this precision limits in all DCC's so working in a relative scale is totally fine. I'd suggest scale up the model in your game engine if that's supported over there.

Answer (score 5):

- The limitation is on *size* of objects, not actual vertex location.
  And according to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48028/78972), there's no way around it.
- The limit is actually ±10 000, so the maximum size of objects is 20 000 BU.

**Workaround**

- Move your origin point.
- Since the zero point for this limitation is object's origin point, you can make a mountain 20 000 m high, by moving the origin point higher.

[image]

Funny sidenote:
It's actually 10 000 *Blender units* (which correspond to meters), so for Imperial units, the limit is 32808.4 ft.

Comment: I tried to enter 10001 as you showed in the screenshot, but Blender keeps rewriting it as 10000 m. This is where the problem is. I don't see how you succeeded doing it. @JachymMichal, could you detail the process for your solution?