# weird artifacts in shadows

Tags: rendering, shadows, artifacts

I started to get really weird artifacts popping in my scene, i checked a bit everything i thought of but it doesn t seem to fix the issue. Do you guys have an ideas about that kind of stuff?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? (the head and light only)

Comment: The thing is subdivided wireframe of your mesh rendered only on faces (and probably only in a shade) faced to light :)  Since I'm not sure it can be done accidentally it is brobably a bug? But like moonboots asked ... it would be interesting to see your simplified file :)

Comment: Can you share your .blend file? Maybe all faces were split/separated and it's peterpanning? Or maybe the scale is huge and it causes some weird precision errors? Or some other setting might be at an extreme…

Comment: thanks guys!
you can grab the file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/nt2kw1r7y9epyit5k7l82/test.blend?rlkey=68snx79nu5hi3k0anxqaul2w1&dl=0

Comment: When I press Numpad0, I see nothing, when I press F12, it renders transparent, empty image. Those two things already hint there's something wrong. Also see [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advices](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486)

Comment: ah man actually your comment helped, dont know what the hell i did but all my scene was far from the world origin, i move back everything at the right place and everything seems to work now, if someone has an idea of why it did that i d be curious ^^

Comment: I hinted at it before "Or maybe the scale is huge and it causes some weird precision errors?" - in this case it's not huge, but it's still a float precision problem... You can read this [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263202/can-i-create-a-large-videogame-map-in-blender-like-9-5-kilometers-in-size#comment449273_263202)